# How to make a square follow mouse cursor inside grid

Tags: python, pointers, tkinter, grid, mouse

I'm trying to make a square follow mouse cursor inside Tkinter grid.

I'm using this code to create a grid:

```
for gr in range(0, 400, 10):
    canvas.create_line(0,gr, 400,gr, fill='#cfcfcf', width=1)
for gr in range(0,400, 10):
    canvas.create_line(gr,0, gr,400, fill='#cfcfcf', width=1)
```

I bind canvas to cursor "Motion":

```
def cursor_move(event):
    x, y= event.x, event.y
    cursor = canvas.find_withtag('cursor') #cursor is my square which I want to move
    canvas.moveto(cursor, newx, newy)
```

But I have no idea how to get newx and newy values.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the square snap at the grid?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the square snapping at the grid, try:

```py
def cursor_move(event):
    # calculate grid x and y based on mouse x and y
    x, y = event.x//10*10, event.y//10*10
    canvas.moveto('cursor', x-1, y-1)
```